# Fseek is returning an error code of -1. I am using replit as my compiler

Tags: c

The function that contains the fseek statement is:

```
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, struct Pixel** pArr, int width, int height) {
int padding = (4 - (width % 4)) % 4;
for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
  for (int col = 0; col < width; ++col) {
    unsigned char b,g,r;
    fread(&b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
    fread(&g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
    fread(&r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
    pArr[row][col].b = b;
    pArr[row][col].g = g;
    pArr[row][col].r = r;
  }
  if (padding != 0) {
        fseek(file, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }      
  }
}
```

I tried commenting out each line until I found the line that when commented out caused the program to execute with no error. The line containing the fseek statement is the culprit. But I do not understand why fseek is giving error code -1.

Comment: `fseek(file, padding, SEEK_CUR);` does not show how -1 was read.  Post code that examines the return value of `fseek()`.

Comment: Probably because you've not read my correction to the calculation of `padding` in the question you asked previously. (The UV'd answer is wrong, too.) In the calculation you've used, you consider _width_ **pixels**, not _width * 3_ for **bytes**. 59 pixels would require 1 pixel of padding... This is not the point. 59 pixels = 177 bytes, requiring 3 **bytes** of padding. ... You're probably seeking off the end of the file (or something similar.) Go back and read ALL the comments under your previous post..

Comment: When it returns non-zero, it also sets `errno`. So use something like `if ( fseek( ... ) ) { perror( "fseek" ); exit( 1 ); }`. There's really only two possibilities: Bad inputs (not a valid file handle, or not a valid position), or the file handle doesn't support seeking (pipe or socket)

Answer (score 1):

I corrected *my* mistake in the comments below your previous question. The code you've shown here does not reflect that correction.

Below *might* work better for you. (I make no claims that the "bgr" sequence is correct. This is up to the OP.)

```
void readPixelsBMP( FILE *fp, struct Pixel pArr[], int cols, int rows ) {
    int padding = (4 - ((cols*3) % 4)) % 4; // corrected calculation # of padding bytes

    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) { // better variable names
        unsigned char bgr[ 3 ]; // 3 at a time...
        for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            fread( bgr, sizeof bgr, 1, fp ); // 3 at a time...
            // Not sure how your 2D array worked in the code presented!
            pArr[r * cols + c].b = bgr[0]; // blue
            pArr[r * cols + c].g = bgr[1]; // green
            pArr[r * cols + c].r = bgr[2]; // red
        }
        if( padding )
            fread( bgr, 1, padding, fp ); // consume padding bytes (if any)
    }
}
```

No need for `fseek()`...

(Credit Chux - Reinstate Monika for corrections. *blush*)